# Include content from one page to another

Tags: pages, include

I'd like to include content from one Page (named "contact_text") to another Page in a specific spot (both of these are WordPress admin pages).
I've followed [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090698/wordpress-include-content-of-one-page-in-another).

However I don't believe I can call a PHP function inside a WP Page, much less at the spot I'd like it to appear. Do I need to set up a shortcode for that function in order to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Another shortcode option (add the following to your functions.php). With this one, you have two options. You can query by the post/page ID (will work for any post type), or the page name/slug (only works for pages).

```
// Add "Show Content" Shortcode
function wpse_120886_show_content( $atts ) {
    // Attributes
    $a = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => null,
            'page_name' => null,
        ), $atts )
    );
    // Get Content & Return
    if ( $a['id'] ) {
        $the_post = get_post( $a['id'] );
        $the_content = $the_post->post_content;
    } elseif ( $a['page_name'] ) {
        $the_post = get_posts( array( 'name' => $a['page_name'], 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) );
        $the_content = $the_post[0]->post_content;
    }
    return $the_content;
}
add_shortcode( 'show_content', 'wpse_120886_show_content' );
```

**Usage**:

By ID: `[show_content id="ID_HERE"]`

By Name/Slug: `[show_content page_name="contact_text"]`

Comment: You should not be using `extract()` Check the docs on how to properly create a shortcode

Comment: The clip was created per the instructions in the WordPress codex. I used extract, which Pieter didn't like, so it's updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could take exactly that code and apply into a shortcode if you want.

```
add_shortcode( 'show_post', 'show_post_shortcode' );

function show_posts_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'path' => null 
    );

    $attributes = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts );

    if ( null === $attributes['path'] )
        return;

    ob_start();

    show_post( $attributes['path'] );

    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    @ob_end_clean();

    return $contents;
}
```

You then just type `[show_post path="about"]` to get the about page content.

Comment: Why are you using output buffering here?

Comment: @KristianVitozev thats because the linked show_post function directly echos. For shortcodes to work correctly you must return the content, else it will always appear before any other output.

Comment: Thank you Zogot...it doesn't work, perhaps I'm missing something. I've pasted the above function into my functions.php, then used [show_post path="contact_copy"] in a page named "contact" at the spot I want that page content to appear. The shortcode text appears on the rendered page, not the content. BTW the source permalink looks like this, but will be a www domain when it's live:  http://192.168.1.230/contact_copy

Comment: Update: I think I'd found a typo (s on show_posts_shortcode), however the new result is a broken, mostly empty page. Perhaps my path to the source is wrong? Thanks again -B